# Eclipse won't allow me to select Dynamic Web Module in Project Facets

Tags: eclipse, war

I'm new to Eclipse, and trying to enable "Dynamic Web Module" within Project Facets. Every time I select it and then apply, it simply unchecks itself. I've tried different versions of it, rebuilding/cleaning, creating a new
"Web Dynamic" project, but the behavior remains the same. What am I missing?

Below is the preference screen. The project is a tutorial for using RESTful web services.

[image]

From the log file:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.IJobManager org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getJobManager()'
at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.internal.FacetsPropertyPage.performOk(FacetsPropertyPage.java:289)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.internal.FacetsPropertyPage.performApply(FacetsPropertyPage.java:313)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.lambda$1(PreferencePage.java:289)
at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.run(PropertyDialogAction.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.ProjectPropertyDialogAction.run(ProjectPropertyDialogAction.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.IJobManager org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getJobManager()'
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.WorkbenchResourceHelper$FileAdapter.getSaveLock(WorkbenchResourceHelper.java:157)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.WorkbenchResourceHelper$FileAdapter.aquireSaveLock(WorkbenchResourceHelper.java:141)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.WorkbenchResourceHelper$FileAdapter.isConsistent(WorkbenchResourceHelper.java:213)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.WorkbenchResourceHelper.isConsistent(WorkbenchResourceHelper.java:314)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.validateedit.ResourceStateValidatorImpl.getInconsistentResources(ResourceStateValidatorImpl.java:283)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.validateedit.ResourceStateValidatorImpl.checkConsistency(ResourceStateValidatorImpl.java:150)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.validateedit.ResourceStateValidatorImpl.checkActivation(ResourceStateValidatorImpl.java:75)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.integration.EditModel.checkActivation(EditModel.java:628)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.ModuleStructuralModel.checkActivation(ModuleStructuralModel.java:319)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.listeners.ValidateEditListener.validateState(ValidateEditListener.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.listeners.ValidateEditListener.validateState(ValidateEditListener.java:330)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.StructureEdit.validateEdit(StructureEdit.java:972)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.StructureEdit.saveIfNecessary(StructureEdit.java:395)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualComponent.create(VirtualComponent.java:373)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web.project.facet.WebFacetInstallDelegate.execute(WebFacetInstallDelegate.java:100)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.callDelegate(FacetedProject.java:1477)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modifyInternal(FacetedProject.java:441)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChangesInternal(FacetedProject.java:1181)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.access$2(FacetedProject.java:1117)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject$5.run(FacetedProject.java:1099)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2380)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2405)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChanges(FacetedProject.java:1109)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.commitChanges(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:2020)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.internal.FacetsPropertyPage$4.run(FacetsPropertyPage.java:232)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2380)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2405)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.internal.FacetsPropertyPage$5.run(FacetsPropertyPage.java:246)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Thank you for the followup!

Comment: Can you add a screen shot, and explain what the project already is?

Comment: Does anything appear in the Error Log view when you click Apply? What's behind the link to Further Configuration Available?